# Restore Backbone.js collection from localstorage

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

In Backbone.js, I am saving an array of collections to localstorage like so:

```
for (var thing of app.things) {
    localStorage.setItem('thing-' + thing.cid, JSON.stringify(thing.collection.toJSON()));
}
```

I can confirm these are being stored in the Chrome localstorage inspector.

I am trying to restore them with this code:

```
var localStorageRef = localStorage.getItem('thing-' + thing.cid);
if (localStorageRef) {
    thing.collection = JSON.parse(localStorageRef);
}
```

This doesn't throw an error, but it does mean that the *next time* I try to trigger the first code (to `setItem`) the following error occurs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: stave.collection.toJSON is not a function
```

Something in my second chunk of code is making the first chunk not work any longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're replacing `thing.collection` with a simple array. Instead, [reset](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) the content of the collection with the parsed data.

```
thing.collection.reset(JSON.parse(localStorageRef));
```

Or if `thing.collection` is not a collection already, create a new one:

```
thing.collection = new Backbone.Collection(JSON.parse(localStorageRef));
```